# Precise theoretical energy of the dihydrogen molecule as a function of internuclear distance?

Tags: resource-recommendations, physical-chemistry, hydrogen, molecules

I am currently looking for the most state-of-the-art theoretical prevision of the energy of the dihydrogen molecule as a function of internuclear distance as a means of comparison with numerical results. However I have been unable to find a clear literature in which such a table would be presented. Could anyone send me the link to such an article if they know one?

Comment: Have you used the search term "potential energy surface" for this?

Comment: I think this publication contains a table https://aip.scitation.org/doi/10.1063/1.465303, but I do not know if it fits the requirement "the most state-of-the-art theoretical prevision". You can also include hydrogen dissociation energy in the search. Publications with that topic also include the energy as function of distance in many cases.

Comment: Probably Coupled Cluster or Configuration Interaction are the key words you want to look for. Essentially numerical methods to solve the many-body problem efficiently.

Comment: Thank you for the replies, @HansWurst that will do I think !  As a matter of fact including hydrogen dissociation energy made my research less fruitful (just as potential energy surface), and had me wondered what would be more appropriate to actually find. Anyways, thank you again